# How to pass arguments in visual studio code for gdb debug

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I want to use the arguments when I debug my C program using visual studio code. In the following example, I would like to execute the program with "-e1" as an argument. Please can you help with the correct modifications of the launch.json file?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/prog/prog",
            "args": ["-e1"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "miDebuggerPath": "/home/rafik/gdb",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the configuration you show us?

Comment: The problem is the debug cannot be run with this syntax of args. Can you help?

Comment: Are you sure your binary is in "${workspaceFolder}/bin/prog/prog"?

Comment: Yes my binary is located in bin/prog/ and the name of the programme is prog

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to pass arguments to the **debuggee**, not the **debugger**. Add another setup command for GDB, presumably like this:

```json
{
    // ...
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            // ...
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set arguments to debuggee",
                    "text": "set args -e1",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*Disclaimer: I don't use VSC and so my answer might be wrong in details. You are invited to correct it.*

Answer (score 0):

It appears using 'args' is correct.

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

> args
>
> JSON array of command-line arguments to pass to the program when it is launched. Example `["arg1", "arg2"]`. If you are escaping characters, you will need to double escape them. For example, `["{\\\"arg1\\\": true}"]` will send `{"arg1": true}` to your application